# My API works fine on IIS Express but Its not Working on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I have a webapi witch I want to post files to it,
my api port on swagger is 5146 and my port on IIS is 8000,

so the problem is that everything works fine in both,
and sending file also works fine on swagger port, but as soon as I change it to 8000 (to read it from IIS), it does not work, in postman the error is 500 (internal server error).
so i don't know what is the problem.

this is my post method:

```
        public static async Task UploadUserPic(MainWindow mainW, ImageBrush IMGbrush)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                string uri =  mainW.ApiUri + "resources/UploadUserPic?id=" + mainW.UBI.ID;
                //var path = @"C:\Users\Kian\Desktop\20220213_08402dd5.jpg";
                var recuestcontent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                //var filestream = File.OpenRead(path);
                var bmp = new BitmapImage();
                var str = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(Convertors.ToString(IMGbrush)));
                recuestcontent.Add(new StreamContent(str), "iformfile", mainW.UBI.ID);
                client.PostAsync(uri, recuestcontent).Wait();
                
            }
        }
```

this is my controller:

```
        // POST api/UsersController
        [HttpPost("UploadUserPic")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadUserPic([FromForm] IFormFile iformfile, string id)
        {
            var resault = await resource_service.UploadUserPic(iformfile, id);
            return Ok(resault);
        }
```

this is my service:

```
        public async Task<string> UploadUserPic(IFormFile iformfile,string id)
        {
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Kian\Desktop\info.txt", "Got");
            string? filename = null;
            try
            {
                filename = id + ".jpg";

                string fileDIR = MyClasses.Paths.ResourcesDirectory() + "UsersPics\\";

                if (!Directory.Exists(fileDIR))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDIR);

                string filepath = fileDIR + filename;


                if (File.Exists(filepath))
                {
                    File.Delete(filepath);
                }

                using (var filestream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await iformfile.CopyToAsync(filestream);
                }
                return filename;
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            return filename;
        }
```

and resourcesdirectory() comes from here:

```
        public static string GetCurentDirectory()
        {
            var resault = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            return resault;
        }

        public static string ResourcesDirectory()
        {
            var resault = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Resources\\");
            if (!Directory.Exists(resault))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(resault);

            return resault;
        }
```

Comment: log the error, and add error description here

Comment: check your launchSettings.json. See what have you defined under iis

Comment: @afrose this is under IIS:
`
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
`

Comment: @DivyangDesai
I'm no sure what you mean by logging the error?

Comment: @KianFeizbahr what about applicationUrl and sslPorts ? Are you specifying it correctly when calling from postman? Also, I see that it the controller has parameter of type `IFormFile`, so are you correcly populating the file from postman? What I mean to say is that if you put a breakpoint on the controller method is it hitting the breakpoint?

Comment: @afrose well the point is it all works in postman when I'm using swagger port, even in my IIS everything else works fine, the only thing that is not working is my file sending, I can send file when my local Swagger IP:Port is running, means the codes are OK, it just can not send to my uploadfile controller on IIS

Comment: I found something else: it works fine on get, i think there is some issue with write permission, although I gave both write and read permission to the folder

Comment: People usually don't say "on swagger", and IIS Express isn't IIS. So, to stop others from guessing what's up, edit the question to include screenshots about those settings.

Comment: I found something new... my response body in iisexpress goes with my file in postman but in iis it goes empty! and in both of them, in request body iformfile is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I found two points that we need to pay attention to, you can check them.

**1. IIS permission to access the folder**

I saw your hardcode the path like `C:\Users\Kian\Desktop\info.txt`. You can read and write it in another drive, not C: drive.

**2. You need to check the folder structure, make sure it is same as the Debug model. (You can find the debug files inside bin folder)**

I mean you need check `UsersPics` and `Resources` folder (and so on) if it exist.

Comment: thanks json
well, the thing is the permission is ok, and IISuser has the permission for read and write,
that path you saw , it was just for testing to see if my service works or not, and it did not even go through controller.(should be erased)
and for the second part, well, everything else works on IIS,( like posting and getting from my DB), the only thing that works only in swagger and not on IIS is this file send, so if folder structure had problem it shouldn't have worked at all.

Comment: I found something else: it works fine on get, i think there is some issue with write permission, although I gave both write and read permission to the folder

Comment: Hi @KianFeizbahr, please put your publish files to other dirves like my answer mentioned. It could help you test it quickly.

Comment: I tried it and I got the same issue

Comment: @KianFeizbahr Could you create a minimal sample for us to test? Please hide sensitive information.

Comment: Sure, i'll post it